# How to get spreadsheets from a specific Google Drive folder?

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The code provided in this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets#retrieve_a_list_of_spreadsheets) (snippet given below) retrieves a list of all the spreadsheets for the authenticated user.

```
public class MySpreadsheetIntegration {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AuthenticationException,
        MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");

        // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)

        // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

        // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,
            SpreadsheetFeed.class);
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

        // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
        for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
            // Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
            System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to get all the spreadsheets. I only want to get those spreadsheets that are in a particular folder (if the folder exists, otherwise terminate the program). Is it possible using this API? If yes, how?

As far as my understanding goes, the SpreadsheetFeed has to be changed. But I didn't get any example snippet against it.

Comment: I don't think Spreadsheet API even has a concept of "folder". You need [children.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list#request) from Drive API. This returns a list of files, not of spreadsheets; but the URLs contain Spreadsheet Ids, so you can try to access them this way...  Or just use Apps Script API instead, which provides a clean way to pass File object  to SpreadsheetApp, returning a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Meta Ok, I understood. But I have to get the folder first. Also, can I get SpreadsheetEntry from fileId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out the solution as follows:

First, get the fileId of that particular folder. Use `setQ()` to pass query checking for folder and folder name. The following snippet will be useful:

```
result = driveService.files().list()
         .setQ("mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
                AND title='" + folderName + "'")
         .setPageToken(pageToken)
         .execute();
```

Then, get the list of files in that particular folder. I found it from this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list#examples). Snippet is as follows:

```
private static void printFilesInFolder(Drive service, String folderId) throws IOException {
    Children.List request = service.children().list(folderId);

    do {
        try {
            ChildList children = request.execute();

            for (ChildReference child : children.getItems()) {
                System.out.println("File Id: " + child.getId());
            }
            request.setPageToken(children.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
        }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
         request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
}
```

Lastly, check for spreadsheets and get worksheet feeds for them. The following snippet might help.

```
URL WORKSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/" + fileId + "/private/full");

WorksheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(WORKSHEET_FEED_URL, WorksheetFeed.class);
worksheets = feed.getEntries();
```